# How to bulk delete duplicates in erpnext

Tags: data-cleaning, delete-row, erpnext, drop-duplicates

How to bulk delete duplicates in erpnext

I tried doing this in data import>update existing records but the downloaded file is 20mb and allowed import file size is 10mb

I want to know how we can delete duplicates.......

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.